# Laravel Package - artisan vendor publish command not working

Tags: package, composer-php, laravel-5, integration

I'm new to Laravel, trying to install packages. I've tried many packages to include in my project like [AdminLTE](https://packagist.org/packages/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte) and [Blogify](https://packagist.org/packages/jorenvanhocht/blogify). as the [AdminLTE manual](https://packagist.org/packages/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte) and [Blogify manual](http://www.blogify.io/docs) says exactely.

Installed the packages using composer:

```
Composer require <package>
```

I've tried to publish the packages to use:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

or publish as said in the manuals, but the command gives me output:

> Nothing to publish

and public folder doesn't change at all and no folders or files added.

**How** to integrate these packages into my Laravel 5.2 app in right way?

**If possible** can some one explain what is the problem and how to get over it and have ability to use it in my blades?

**Note**: I'm using *Windows 10* and *XAMP* local server,I cant use commands like `npm` and any thing related to *Mac*

Comment: Did you follow all the steps ?

Comment: yes, and after all **public** folder still doesn't have any changes

Comment: and *Blogify* haven't any migrations

Comment: Could you update the question with the exact steps(commands)  you used. For AdminLte

Comment: Same as manual,  exact steps

Comment: I will try with my box and will let you know soon

Comment: Really appreciate your help Jay

Comment: I will wait for it

Comment: Mine was successful ... I will put my steps in answer..

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: `composer require jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte`

```
 C:\wamp\blog>composer require jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte
    You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
    Using version ^1.6 for jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte
    ./composer.json has been updated
    > php artisan clear-compiled
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
      - Installing jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte (v1.6.5)
        Downloading: 100%

    Writing lock file
    Generating autoload files
    > php artisan optimize
    Generating optimized class loader
```

Step 2:Add the service provider to the providers in config/app.php:
Step 3:`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\ServiceProvider" --tag=assets`

```
C:\wamp\blog>php artisan vendor:publish --provider="JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\ServiceProvider" --tag=assets
Copied Directory [\vendor\jeroennoten\laravel-adminlte\resources\assets] To [\public\vendor\adminlte]
Publishing complete for tag [assets]!
```

Comment: As I understood you were having problem in step 3. right ?